# netezza nzsql/SQL: How to do limit or top in update statement?

Tags: sql, database, limit, netezza

I´m trying to execute following statement:

```
UPDATE refixy_zakladni_tabulka
SET u_Marketingova_akce_vysledek_bit = dbo.Data_Marketingove_akce.Výsledek
FROM dbo.Data_Marketingove_akce
WHERE dbo.Data_Marketingove_akce.CisloSluzby = dbo.Refixy_Zakladni_tabulka.u_Sluzba AND
(dbo.Refixy_Zakladni_tabulka.u_Cas_Refixace_datum BETWEEN
dbo.Data_Marketingove_akce.Cas_Refixace_datum_od
AND dbo.Data_Marketingove_akce.Cas_Refixace_datum_do)
```

The result is canceled update due to attemp to update a target row with multiple join rows. I understand that the WHERE clause may return multiple records so it is impossible to update. But if this occurs, I only need first record that meet the WHERE clause, so I would like to use TOP or LIMIT to do so. Unfortunately TOP is no use in UPDATE statement and my attemps to add LIMIT to the statement fails with:

> found "LIMIT" (at char 389) expecting a keyword

Complete statement with limit clause looks like this:

```
UPDATE refixy_zakladni_tabulka
SET u_Marketingova_akce_vysledek_bit = dbo.Data_Marketingove_akce.Výsledek
FROM dbo.Data_Marketingove_akce
WHERE dbo.Data_Marketingove_akce.CisloSluzby = dbo.Refixy_Zakladni_tabulka.u_Sluzba AND
(dbo.Refixy_Zakladni_tabulka.u_Cas_Refixace_datum BETWEEN
dbo.Data_Marketingove_akce.Cas_Refixace_datum_od
AND dbo.Data_Marketingove_akce.Cas_Refixace_datum_do) LIMIT 1
```

How can I make this work?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a window aggregate function in a subselect to achieve this. I use row_number in this example.

```
create table update_target (col1 bigint, col2 bigint);
create table update_ref (col1 bigint, col2 bigint);

insert into update_target values (1,10);
insert into update_target values (1,11);
insert into update_target values (1,12);
insert into update_target values (2,20);
insert into update_target values (2,21);
insert into update_target values (2,22);

insert into update_ref values (1,100);
insert into update_ref values (1,101);
insert into update_ref values (2,200);
insert into update_ref values (2,201);


UPDATE update_target a
SET a.col2 = foo.col2
FROM (
      SELECT col1,
         col2,
         row_number() over (partition BY col1 ORDER BY col2) rownum
      FROM update_ref
   )
   foo
WHERE a.col1   = foo.col1
AND foo.rownum = 1;

select * from update_target order by col1;

 COL1 | COL2
------+------
    1 |  100
    1 |  100
    1 |  100
    2 |  200
    2 |  200
    2 |  200
(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `netezza` you can be sure to avoid this error by using `rowid`.  Try the following query.

```
update refixy_zakladni_tabulka set u_Marketingova_akce_vysledek_bit =dbo.Data_Marketingove_akce.Výsledek
from (select distinct a.rowid as row_id, b.Výsledek
from refixy_zakladni_tabulka a inner join
dbo.Data_Marketingove_akce b
on a.u_Sluzba=b.CisloSluzby
and a.u_Cas_Refixace_datum between b.Cas_Refixace_datum_od and b.Cas_Refixace_datum_do) dbo
where rowid=dbo.row_id
```